# crossdomain.xml in AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I got URI error notification for `/crossdomain.xml` at dashboard in admin console of appengine.

- How to fix the error?

Comment: Are you hosting crossdomain.xml or just wondering about the error message?

Comment: and i don't know about `crossdomain.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Adobe's site](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html):

> A cross-domain policy file is an XML document that grants a web
>   client—such as Adobe Flash Player, Adobe Reader, etc.—permission to
>   handle data across multiple domains. When a client hosts content from
>   a particular source domain and that content makes requests directed
>   towards a domain other than its own, the remote domain would need to
>   host a cross-domain policy file that grants access to the source
>   domain, allowing the client to continue with the transaction. Policy
>   files grant read access to data, permit a client to include custom
>   headers in cross-domain requests, and are also used with sockets to
>   grant permissions for socket-based connections.

`crossdomain.xml` is an example of this type of cross-domain policy file.

In the context of your site, someone (maybe you, maybe someone else) is trying to access content from your site from within an Adobe application. The application, trying to be a good citizen, is checking for the existence of a cross-domain policy file before performing the actions. Since you haven't provided one, you're getting a `404` in your log.

The easiest fix is to write a `crossdomain.xml` file, and serve it from your App Engine app. Adobe apps that are looking for it will now get a file instead of a `404` and the error will stop appearing in your log.

Alternatively, you can just ignore the error. Like with a missing `robots.txt` file, the `404` errors aren't doing damage to your site, they are just occasionally populating your logs with errors you don't care about.